# how to use Cython to run function with multiple 2d numpy arrays as input and return an 2d array?

Tags: arrays, numpy, for-loop, cython

I am attempting to use cython for the first time to speed up a function containing a for-loop. The function itself takes in 3 inputs: Q_t which is a 2d numpy array (dtype = float16), I_ which is a 2d array of random indices (dtype = np.int32), and then a scalar value 'v' (dtype float).

The function itself is simple, it updates the elements of Q_t by slicing the Q_t array using the indices contained in I_ row by row in a for-loop.

I am struggling to work out how to implement this using cython - could anyone help? Reason for doing this is to try speed up this for-loop as the dimensionality of Q_t and I_ means that this for-loop appears to be the slowest part of my code and I don't believe I can get away from using the loop (i.e. vectorisation wont help).

The below code is the working numpy implementation:

```py
def updateQ_t(Q_t, I_, v):
  for i in range(0, len(I_)):  
    Q_t[I_[i,:]] += v
  return Q_t
```

Comment: See the doc about memory views: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html . You need to give a type to the variables (like `Q_t`). Note that adding a loop on `I_[i,:]` is certainly needed to get good performances.